# Similar sums $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}=\frac{\pi ^3}{32}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Is it possible to find $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3}$ if we know that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}$?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can be solved via Riemann zeta functions  by partitioning the denominators into even and odd, Anwer will be $\frac{3}{4} \zeta (3) \approx 0.902 $

Comment: Refer here for Riemann Zeta functions : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, but nevertheless they are some how related as we will shortly see below.
Lets start by the first series which is an instance of the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) $\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$, which is related to the [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) by the equation

\begin{align*}
\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s) \tag{1}
\end{align*}

In your case $s=3$, therefore,  by $(1)$ we obtain

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3}=\frac34\zeta(3) 
\end{align*}

The second series is an instance of the [Dirichlet Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) which is defined by

\begin{align*}
\beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^s}
\end{align*}

One relation between these two functions can be established by yet another function, the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) given by

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Li}_s(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{x^n}{n^s} \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Setting $x=\sqrt{-1}=i$ in $(2)$ we obtain

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Li}_s(i)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{i^n}{n^s} \\
&=\frac{i}{1^s}-\frac{1}{2^s}-\frac{i}{3^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+ \cdots\\
&=i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^s}{(2n+1)^s}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)^s}\\
&=i\beta(s)-\frac{1}{2^s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}\\
&=i\beta(s)-2^{-s}\eta(s)\\
 \end{align*}

For $s=3$ we obtain

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Li}_3(i)&=i\beta(3)-\frac18\eta(3)\\
&=i \frac{\pi^3}{32}-\frac{3}{32}\zeta(3)
 \end{align*}

One interesting fact to note is that the Riemann zeta function and consequently the Dirichlet eta function can be expressed in closed form for $n$ even, and the Dirichlet Beta function can be expressed in closed form for odd indices.

Hope this somehow helps you.